# Using ngModel for form validation

Tags: html, angularjs, validation

Consider this html

```
<input type="text" name="txt" ng-model="ctrl.txt">
```

I want to write my own form-validation mechanism in an Angular 1 app. **Is it a good practice** to base the validation on the value of the ngModel that is bind to the input element instead of the actual input value (as it done in the built-in angular form validator)?

In other words, is there a reason to avoid doing that (for any input type)?

(PS I'm familiar with the standard Angular form validation. No need to suggest using it)

Comment: wich type of validateion, and exact version of angular is using 1.3, 1.4...

Comment: normal form validations (required, max-length etc). angular 1.5.2

Comment: this is inside angular from default https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input

Comment: its not answering my question

Comment: 've re-read it and, sorry, this not a valid answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is worth doing a small introduction to validation.

**Front end validation is no validation**, if you want to persist your data to a server. 
It is best practice to validate inputdata server side before saving there somewhere.

In case you whish to "prevalidate" the user input to avoid a future reiteration because of a wrong input, then best practice is to use the standard features of Angular and not reinvent the wheel with custom controller function (even if it is possible).

[angular forms guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)

I hope it helps.